# Sort data frame by character and date columns

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, dataset

I'm trying to sort a simple dataset by a character column (descending) and a date variable (ascending).

```
   fx_code  date    fx_spot 
1      AUD 2000-01-31  0.6370  
2      AUD 2000-02-29  0.6178   
3      AUD 2000-03-31  0.6071   
4      AUD 2000-04-28  0.5839   
5      AUD 2000-05-31  0.5725
```

When I run the following code

```
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
DF <- DF[order(DF$fx_code,-DF$date),]
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in `-.Date`(DF$date) : unary - is not defined for "Date" objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as.numeric` would be more understandable:

```
DF <- DF[order(DF$fx_code, - as.numeric(DF$date)), ]
```

Under the hood, this is what `xtfrm` actually does:

```
> xtfrm(as.Date('2000-04-29', format='%Y-%m-%d'))
[1] 11076
> as.numeric(as.Date('2000-04-29', format='%Y-%m-%d'))
[1] 11076
```

Comment: Have I to add `as.Date` before `as.numeric` to the date before ordering or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DF <- DF[order(DF$fx_code, - xtfrm(DF$date)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
rev(order(date_field))
DF <- DF[rev(order(DF$date))]
```